# Jboss 7.2 root-logger level DEBUG provokes ConcurrentModificationException on executing a jpa query

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, jboss7.x, concurrentmodification

Environment:

- JBoss 7.2.0
- Java 11
- Hibernate 5.3.15.Final

I am getting an error ConcurrentModificationException on executing jpa query from a method in stateless ejb. It was working until now and no idea what it could be. The query is only getting records in a condition.

**Error log**

```
13:06:24,419 ERROR [es.caib.accfor.presentation.back.security.UserPrincipalManager] (default task-1) Error UserPrincipalManager.doFilter: es.caib.accfor.business.AppException: Exception UsuarioService.trace
    at deployment.accfor2.ear.accfor-ejb.jar//es.caib.accfor.business.security.boundary.UsuariService.trace(UsuariService.java:254)
    ...
    Suppressed: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:114)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:122)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:256)
        ... 106 more
    Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
        at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1300)
        at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:126)
        at org.jboss.jts.integration//com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:89)
        at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.2.Final-redhat-1//org.wildfly.transaction.client.LocalTransaction.commitAndDissociate(LocalTransaction.java:77)
        at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.2.Final-redhat-1//org.wildfly.transaction.client.ContextTransactionManager.commit(ContextTransactionManager.java:71)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:88)
        ... 108 more
        Suppressed: javax.transaction.RollbackException: WFTXN0061: Transaction is marked rollback-only
            ...
        Suppressed: javax.transaction.RollbackException: WFTXN0061: Transaction is marked rollback-only
            ...
    Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1493)
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:1526)
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:1524)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.7.Final-redhat-00001//org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter.toString(EntityPrinter.java:104)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.7.Final-redhat-00001//org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.logFlushResults(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:129)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.7.Final-redhat-00001//org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:105)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.7.Final-redhat-00001//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:38)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.7.Final-redhat-00001//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1454)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.7.Final-redhat-00001//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:511)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.7.Final-redhat-00001//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3283)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.7.Final-redhat-00001//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2479)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.7.Final-redhat-00001//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.7.Final-redhat-00001//org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:352)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.7.Final-redhat-00001//org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:47)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.7.Final-redhat-00001//org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:37)
        at org.jboss.as.transactions@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.txn.service.internal.tsr.JCAOrderedLastSynchronizationList.beforeCompletion(JCAOrderedLastSynchronizationList.java:113)
        at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.2.Final-redhat-1//org.wildfly.transaction.client.AbstractTransaction.performConsumer(AbstractTransaction.java:236)
        at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.2.Final-redhat-1//org.wildfly.transaction.client.AbstractTransaction.performConsumer(AbstractTransaction.java:247)
        at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.2.Final-redhat-1//org.wildfly.transaction.client.AbstractTransaction$AssociatingSynchronization.beforeCompletion(AbstractTransaction.java:292)
        at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76)
        at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:360)
        at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:91)
        at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162)
        at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1288)
        ... 113 more
```

**UserPrincipalManager(filter)**

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "UserPrincipalFilter", urlPatterns = "/*")
public class UserPrincipalManager implements Filter {

    @Inject
    private UsuariServiceable usuariSvc;


    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws java.io.IOException, ServletException {
        ...
        Usuari usuari = usuariSvc.trace(loadUserData(sReq.getUserPrincipal()));
        ...
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }
```

**UserService**

```
@RolesAllowed("**")
@Stateless
public class UserService {
    ...

    public Usuari trace(UserPrincipal uPrincipal) throws AppException {
       //I tried a simple db query and also get this error ConcurrentModificationException without anything else
       ...
       List<VTaula> rolNames = vTaulaSvc.findByNames(rolsToAdd); //Error by calling findByNames(HashSet<String>)
       ...
    }
}
```

**VTaulaService**

```
@PermitAll
@Stateless
public class VTaulaService extends BusinessService<VTaula> implements VTaulaServiceable {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "appPU")
    protected EntityManager eManager;
    ...
    public List<VTaula> findByNames(Set<String> names) throws AppException {
        List<VTaula> vTaulas;

        try {
            Query q = eManager.createNamedQuery("SELECT g FROM VTaula g WHERE g.nomCA IN (:names)");
            q.setParameter("names", names);
            vTaulas = q.getResultList();  //Error ConcurrentModificationException

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("findByNomCA", e);
            throw new AppException("Error VTaula " + e, e);
        }

        return vTaulas;
    }

    ...
}
```

**standalone.xml**

```
...
<root-logger>
   <level name="DEBUG"/>
   <handlers>
       <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
       <handler name="FILE"/>
   </handlers>
</root-logger>
...

//Also happen with org.hibernate
 <logger category="org.hibernate">
     <level name="DEBUG"/>
 </logger>
```

Comment: Not sure if related but the parameter name is `nomsCA` not `names`. Also, what's `eManager` ?

Comment: that was a typo. eManager is entity Manager for persistence unit

Comment: I can't see any obvious reason for the CME in `q.getResultList();` but I'd have 2 guesses: 1) you might concurrently be modifying `names` - try to make a defensive copy before passing it to `setParameter()`, 2) it might happen somewhere in your `VTaula` entity which you didn't share.

Comment: Also note that `SessionImpl.doFlush()`: Hibernate tries to flush any changes that happend durng the current session before executing the query. That's where the exception is thrown but the source might actually be code that ran before (in the same session, so presumably within `UserService.trace()`. Since the stacktrace mentions it happens in a HashMap look for any modifications to such a map that happens within that transaction and before the `findByNames(...)` call.

Comment: I debugged before findByNames... and I also got the same error so it is a start. I'll follow that clue. Thanks!

Comment: @Thomas I think I found the problem with a standalone.xml server configuration file. When I added on root-logger debug level I get this ConcurrentModificationException but  when I use info works well. Does it have any sense?

Comment: I found something related in redhat webpage https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4390551

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with root-logger and level DEBUG, I just take back that level to INFO and this problems fade away.

The real problem seems to be something related with hibernate log, but no idea what is exactly.

This is a workaraound but I could also use DEBUG level.

**standalone.xml**

```
...
<root-logger>
   <level name="INFO"/>
   <handlers>
       <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
       <handler name="FILE"/>
   </handlers>
</root-logger>
...
```

I added debug level logger avoiding ConcurrentModificationException by doing this way:

Add package logger with CLI

```
/subsystem=logging/logger=com.package:add(level=DEBUG)
/subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE:write-attribute(name=level,value=DEBUG)
```

The result standalone.xml logger looks like this

**standalone.xml**

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:6.0">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="com.package">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
        <formatter name="PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </subsystem>
```

Comment: Well, `org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter.toString(...)` seems to indicate the CME occurs when trying to print the entity, presumably in some debug statement. So disabling that statement by increasing the log level might work as a workaround as you described but the root cause of the problem seems to still be somewhere in your code. There might actually be a bug in Hibernate but this is less likely than your code being the culprit - did you try to step through the code with a debugger to see where the modifications happen?

Comment: I tried to reproduce with another project from github and with a simple jpa query and same error, so it looks that something is going on with hibernate... but I can't say what is it